# MySQL sort conditionally on two joined columns

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table structured with two date fields, like so:

```
uid int auto-increment
sponsor_name varchar
date_sent datetime
date_resent datetime
```

Let's assume data like:

```
(1, 'patrick', '2014-03-01 12:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
(2, 'patrick', '2014-03-05 14:30:00', '2014-03-18 00:30:00' )
(3, 'patrick', '2014-03-08 16:30:00', '2014-03-24 00:00:00' )
(4, 'patrick', '2014-03-20 12:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_resent DESC` I see data returned as expected with the rows having some `date_resent` first, followed by those without:

```
(3, 'patrick', '2014-03-08 16:30:00', '2014-03-24 00:00:00' )
(2, 'patrick', '2014-03-05 14:30:00', '2014-03-18 00:30:00' )
(1, 'patrick', '2014-03-01 12:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
(4, 'patrick', '2014-03-20 12:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
```

But what I want is to use some combination of both columns `date_sent` and `date_resent`, so that in the case `date_resent` is empty ('000-00-00 00:00:00') the `date_sent` is substituted in the ordering.

The desired result would be data:

```
(3, 'patrick', '2014-03-08 16:30:00', '2014-03-24 00:00:00' )
(4, 'patrick', '2014-03-20 12:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
(2, 'patrick', '2014-03-05 14:30:00', '2014-03-18 00:30:00' )
(1, 'patrick', '2014-03-01 12:30:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY IF(data_resent = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', data_sent, data_resent) DESC
```

Or if `data_resent` when not empty is always greater then `data_sent` (I guess it is), then you could try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY GREATEST(data_sent, data_resent) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! `GREATEST()` is wonderful to know about and the solution I put into use.